# Why is the Strike Price so low on some Puts

Tags: stocks, put-options

I am using Robinhood and looking at buying a put for BYND.  The current stock price is around $93.00, but most of the puts I find have a strike price in the $40's.  I can't find anything with a breakeven point above $65.  Is this reasonable?  It seems to me you shouldn't have to incur such a large risk just because you think a stock will go down.

Comment: where are you looking at these puts? https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/bynd/option-chain?dateindex=-1&callput=put&money=out seems to indicate there are plenty with higher than $40 strike

Comment: What risk are you incurring? Those puts should be _very_ cheap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am using Robinhood and looking at buying a put for BYND. The current stock price is around $93.00, but most of the puts I find have a strike price in the $40's.

BYND offers strike prices from $35 to $135.

> I can't find anything with a break even point above $65. Is this reasonable? It seems to me you shouldn't have to incur such a large risk just because you think a stock will go down.

The higher the  implied volatility, the higher the option premium.  BYND has a monstrous average implied volatility of about 135% so BYND's option premiums are going to be huge.  I surmise that's what you mean by a "break even point above $65" (strike price less premium paid).   In such cases, buying long options is likely to be a disaster waiting to happen. If you absolutely insist on betting on this one, consider doing  a vertical spread so that you are also selling some of that fat premium, offsetting the fat premium that you'll pay for the long leg.